# Run multiple .sh scripts from one .sh script? CentOS

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, centos

How can I run multiple `.sh` scripts from one `.sh` script and run them all in separate terminals? I already have

> /root/A.sh & /root/B.sh & /root/C.sh

The issue is it runs all of these in the same terminal at the same time, and without the `&'s`, it runs them when the previous one is finished running, how can I make them all startup at the same time in separate terminals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way leveraging gnome terminal tabbing capability :

```
gnome-terminal \
  --tab-with-profile=Default --title=A.sh --command="/root/A.sh" \
  --tab-with-profile=Default --title=B.sh --command="/root/B.sh" \
  --tab-with-profile=Default --title=C.sh --command="/root/C.sh"&
```

Answer (score 1):

You can launch your preferred terminal program (i.e. rxvt, xterm, etc) and pass the command to be executed as an option, as in (for instance):

```
rxvt -display :0 -e "/root/B.sh"&
```

This assumes you're running on the local console with an X server and window manager.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://sites.google.com/site/cciexperience/home/screen-multiple-shell-sessions-in-one-terminal) is a tutorial on how to configure screen for multiple shell sessions and [here](http://www.rackaid.com/resources/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/) is another tutorial on using screen

**edit**

you can check [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/111417/how-to-multitask-in-the-linux-terminal-3-ways-to-use-multiple-shells-at-once/) for using screen and 2 other alternatives for multiprocessing shell

Comment: Is there no simple way to run the multiple scripts in separate terminals at the same time?

Comment: I don't know of a simpler way

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at my pc right now, so I can't test this...

Try including the following in your main script to start sh (or whatever shell you prefer) invoking your script as a background task to stop the main script blocking.

```
sh script1 &
sh script2 &
sh script3 &
```

Kev

Answer (score 0):

With `konsole`, you can have

```
konsole -e command [args]
```

e.g.

```
konsole -e /bin/bash root.sh &  ## For konsole, placing it on the background is optional
```

You can also set the window's title (depends on the version)

```
konsole -p tabtitle="Window title." -e command [args]
```

With `xterm`:

```
xterm -e command [args] &  ## xterm needs to be placed on background.
```