# Using a shell script to call multiple ROS launch files

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, ros

I just found out that I need a quick-and-dirty demo for tomorrow. I'm working with a robot that uses ROS, and we have some packages that make it move in a simple pattern. I want to start all the necessary nodes with one command. The command lines I would need to run--all in separate terminals--are:

**roscore**

**rviz**

**roslaunch [blank move_base map]**

**roslaunch [package] [movement script]**

**rqt_graph**

All of these programs run indefinitely--e.g., **roscore** is a server that coordinates the other nodes. I can't just use "&" to string them together into one line. They each require a dedicated terminal window/process. How can I do that in bash or Python?

Note: I realize it would probably be better to use a custom ROS launch file, but I don't have time.

Comment: try the subprocess module... eg subprocess.call(["your code","code params"],shell=False)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can launch your softwares from the terminal binaries themselves to get a new terminal for each. It would depend on the terminal you use. With `konsole` you can have

```
konsole -e command [args]
...
```

With gnome-terminal you do:

```
gnome-terminal -e command [args] &
```

With xterm:

```
xterm -e command [args] &
```

Probably refer as well to a similar thread: [Run multiple .sh scripts from one .sh script? CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669866/run-multiple-sh-scripts-from-one-sh-script-centos)

Comment: We ended up using xterm. Thanks!